# Exposing link on collection entity in spring data REST

Tags: spring-data, hateoas, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

Using spring data REST I have exposed a `ProjectRepository` that supports listing projects and performing CRUD operations on them. When I go to `http://localhost:8080/projects/` I get the list of projects as I expect.

What I am trying to do is add a custom action to the `_links` section of the JSON response for the Project Collection.

For example, I'd like the call to `http://localhost:8080/projects/` to return something like this:

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/projects/{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "search" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/projects/search"
    },
    "customAction" : {
       "href" : "http://localhost:8080/projects/customAction"
    }
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 0,
    "totalPages" : 0,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

Where `customAction` is defined in some controller.

I've tried creating the following class:

```
public class ProjectCollectionResourceProcessor implements ResourceProcessor<Resource<Collection<Project>>> {

    @Override
    public Resource<Collection<Project>> process(Resource<Collection<Project>> listResource) {
        // code to add the links to customAction here
        return listResource;
    }

}
```

and adding adding the following Bean to my applications configuration:

```
@Bean
public ProjectCollectionResourceProcessor projectCollectionResourceProcessor() {
    return new ProjectCollectionResourceProcessor();
}
```

But `process(...)` doesn't ever seem to get called.  What is the correct way to add links to Collections of resources?

Comment: See also, this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40156413

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The collection resources render an instance of `Resources<Resource<Project>>`, not `Resource<Collection<Project>>`. So if you change the generic typing in your `ResourceProcessor` implementation accordingly that should work as you expect it.

Comment: adding below code didn't help `public class ProjectsResourceProcessor implements
  ResourceProcessor<Resources<Project>> {

 @Autowired
 private EntityLinks entityLinks;

 @Override
 public Resources<Project> process(Resources<Project> resources) {
  resources.add(entityLinks.linkFor(Project.class).slash("custom")
    .withRel("custom"));
  return resources;
 }

}` Using SDR-2.1.0.RELEASE

Comment: In order for me to get it to work I had to implement `ResourceProcessor<PagedResources>` and within the code determine if it was a `Project` resource. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @thorben.jakobsen I'm looking for some resources (learning ones :-) to implement your solution. I have a paged resource as well.

Comment: @thorben.jakobsen I wonder how your search end point link would look if it offered pagination.

Comment: @thorben.jakobsen How did you actually manage to do the type checking? Do you have a generic way to share with otherS?

Comment: This doesn't work, ResourceProcessor<Resources<User>> will not be invoked for my paged aggregate root of /users

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. What worked for me was:

```
public class ProjectsResourceProcessor implements ResourceProcessor<PagedResources<Resource<Project>>> {

    private final @NonNull EntityLinks entityLinks;

    @Override
    public PagedResources<Resource<Project>> process(PagedResources<Resource<Project>> pagedResources) {

       ...

        return pagedResources;
    }
}
```

Comment: when no project exist, links do not appears :'(

Comment: There is an explicit check in ResourcesProcessorWrapper::isValueTypeMatch to check for empty content and it prevents the resource processor from firing.

Comment: yup facing same issue .. any hack to overcome this