# Exposing link on collection entity using spring hateoas

Tags: rest, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I have pretty the same question as it has been asked here ([Exposing link on collection entity in spring data REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24274127/exposing-link-on-collection-entity-in-spring-data-rest)). But nothing from that topic helps me to add custom link to collection call.

```
@Component
public class EventListResourceProcessor implements ResourceProcessor<Resources<Event>> {

    @Autowired
    private RepositoryEntityLinks entityLinks;

    @Override
    public Resources<Event> process(Resources<Event> events) {
        events.add(entityLinks.linkToCollectionResource(Event.class).withRel("events"));
        return events;
    }
}
```

process method is never called in this case.

I need to call http://localhost:8080/event and get the following JSON with my_custom_link under _links section:

```html
{
  "_embedded": {
    "event": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Updated event"
      }]
  },
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/event"
    },
    "profile": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/profile/event"
    },
    "my_custom_link": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/custom/"
    }
  },
  "page": {
    "size": 20,
    "totalElements": 4,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "number": 0
  }
}

}
```

Could you please advise me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I was in a similar situation to your question: I had read through the question/answers you linked and found none of them could solve the problem. Here was the eventual answer to my problem:

```
@Component
public class MyResourceProcessor implements ResourceProcessor<Resource<MyInterface>> {

    @Autowired
    private EntityLinks entityLinks;

    @Override
    public Resource<MyInterface> process(Resource<MyInterface> event) {
        event.add(entityLinks.linkForSingleResource(MyClass.class, event.getContent().getId()).slash("custom").withRel("custom"));
        return event;
    }
}
```

This `process` method was called for each Resource in the relevant collection of Resources being returned. The `MyInterface` interface and `MyClass` class should be replaced with whatever you end up needing, but it was required to be written that way to get this to work. Here are the steps I used to get the `process` method called correctly and to determine the `MyInterface` type.

1. I created a `process` method that simply took `ResourceSupport` as the parameter. I created a breakpoint in the code and inspected what underlying class was extending `ResourceSupport`. In my case it was `PersistentEntityResource`. This explained why using `Resource<MyClass>` or `Resources<MyClass>` were never causing the `process` method to be called: `PersistentEntityResource` extends `Resource<Object>`.
2. I updated the `process` method take `PersistentEntityResource` as the parameter. This caused the `process` method to be called for more than my intended changes. I once again used the breakpoint to inspect the  `PersistentEntityResource` object with the intent of discovering what class could be found in the `Resource<Object>` that it extended. I discovered it was a `Proxy` class, and could not be cast to `MyClass` as I had desired.
3. I followed the answer found here to find out more information about the `Proxy` class: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3344386/1417690. While debugging, I discovered the list of interfaces that helped define this class. One of them was of type `MyProjectionInterface`. I now knew that the reason I couldn't use `Resource<Portal>` was because it was actually a `Resource<MyProjectionInterface>`.
4. I had three different `Projections` that I needed to handle. Instead of creating three separate `ResourcePorcoessors` I created the `MyInterface` and had all three of my `projection` interfaces extend it. The `MyInterface` only contained a `Long getId()` method which all of the `projections` already supported anyway.
5. I updated my code to use `Resource<MyInterface>` and added the `linkForSingleResource` using `MyClass` (that all of the `projections` relate to) and the `getId()` method I had defined in `MyInterface`. This successfully added the desired link to each of the resources being returned.

Hopefully these steps help others discover how to determine what type to use as the parameter for the `process` method.

Answer (score 1):

Because I faced the same issue and I hoped an answer here. The solution is to declare a bean `ResourceProcessor` implementing the right generic type which extends `ResourceSupport`.

In our case for a paginable resource, the right `ResourceSupport` is `PagedResources<Resource<MyInterface>>` as the following sample :

```
@Bean
public ResourceProcessor<PagedResources<Resource<Supplier>>> pageableSupplierProcessor() {
    return new ResourceProcessor<PagedResources<Resource<Supplier>>>() {
        @Override
        public PagedResources<Resource<Supplier>> process(PagedResources<Resource<Supplier>> resources) {
            Method registerMethod;
            try {
                registerMethod = SupplierRegistrationController.class.getMethod("register",
                        RegistrationRequest.class);
                Link registerLink = linkTo(registerMethod, new RegistrationRequest()).withRel("register");
                resources.add(registerLink);
                return resources;
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(e);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: In the latest version as of now, you can now use: ```RepresentationModelProcessor<PagedModel<EntityModel<T>>>```. HTH someone else.